# Can a LinkedIn application perform an action as itself?

Tags: api, rest, linkedin-api

On Twitter, applications can self-sign their requests. It appears that in LinkedIn you necessarily have to have an external user to perform any action. I'd like to run a service that does querying on its own without depending on external user actions. What's the best way to go about this? Getting your developer user's credentials to sign the requests seems the best alternative, but it's a bit hackish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you state correctly, all interaction with the LinkedIn API should be done via an authenticated user. There are items in the API [terms of use](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-apis-terms-use) that prohibit allowing others to use your developer account as well, such as 1.5(b).

Unfortunately, there are no self-sign features supported at this point.